# Java: How to restart a db connection if it froze or disconnected?

Tags: java, multithreading, connection, database-connection

I am having difficulty trying to determine when my connection is interrupted, which happens randomly for me. I have tried setting a timer to indicate if the connection froze (for my case each task that uses the connection should not take more than a couple of seconds), but that does not seem to work.

I should also note for the connection, several threads are running at the same time doing some kind of task, if a thread is still alive or not interrupted and it has been past the allotted time to complete the task, then, to me, that indicates there is a connection problem.

Here is the gist of what I have done:

```
        public void run(){
            super.run();

            try {

                    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
                    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {


                            if(isAlive() || interrupted()){//there is a problem with the connection, but I never enter this case...

                                interrupt();
                                timer.cancel();
                                //end the connection and restart it all over again
                                try {
                                    conn.close();
                                    restartConnection();
                                } catch (SQLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                            else{//there is no problem with the connection

                            }
                        }
                    };
                    timer.schedule(task, 5000);//each task should not take anywhere near 5 secs, if it does, then I THINK there is a connection problem
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the db connection freeze occurs when there is a Table lock. The connection will be held by that particular thread till this lock is released. So the next threads will wait for the connections from connection pool which will be empty by now. Please look into if there are any tablelocks.